# WordPress scheduled event not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm building a plugin that tracks the time a user spends at a specific page.
I want a plugin thats updates **every second** to the database, but maybe this isn't the best way. But with this code, it updates only once. Why is that? I hope you can help me!

```
function add_new_intervals( $schedules ) {
    // Adds once every second to the existing schedules.
    $schedules['1sec'] = array(
        'interval' => 1,
        'display' => __( 'Once every second' )
    );
    return $schedules;
 }

// Add new schedule time
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_new_intervals' );


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '1sec', 'my_event');
}


add_action('my_event', 'do_this_every_second');

$counter = 0;

function do_this_every_second() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'myplugin';
    $wpdb->update( 
        $table_name, 
        // Set data
        array( 'visit_time' => $counter),
        // Where
        array('id' => 1) //just for testing
    );
    $counter += 1;
}


register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');
function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_event');
}
```

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just use Google Analytics? It tracks all this info and there are plugins that will integrate it with the WP dashboard.

Comment: @WebElaine It's for a school project. We have to build it ourselves.

Comment: WP Cron only runs when someone is actively using the website, so you may want to look into an actual server cron job rather than a WP one.

Comment: @WebElaine Is there a better way to track the users visited time for each page?

Comment: a better can be that at every page call of the user you save the last time where it was connected. after you just have do calculate the difference between the first and the last time it was visiting a page

Comment: You can run the code every second unless you have a visitor every one second. That's how cron job works.

Comment: @mmm But do you still have to update every second? Because when you do an update when the user navigates to another page, you have a problem when the user closes the browser. Or is there another to solve this?

Comment: Adding to Mmm's point: Google analytics (at least it used to do this) tracks interactions within the session, and then after X-amount of time with no interaction, it ends the session. Maybe setting an action for if time elapsed since last interaction (page load here) is > X, then end tracking for this session/user, then get difference of earliest & latest time stamp. Perhaps weight them if page's end is b/c of elapsed time and not a new page/action. Creates a margin of error, but if user leaves a page open for six days, counting every second is even less reliable data.